# Highlight a row until last column

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

How can I adapt this code to highlight a row until last column, that in my case is “J” and not the EntireRow?

```
 For Each wb In Workbooks
  If wb.Name <> "Book1.xlsm" Then
  wb.Activate

    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
      Set cl = ws.Cells.Find(What:=SearchString, _
        After:=ws.Cells(1, 1), _
        LookIn:=xlValues, _
        LookAt:=xlWhole, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
        SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, _
        SearchFormat:=False)
             If Not cl Is Nothing Then
                 FirstFound = cl.Address
            Do
                  cl.EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = Cor
                 Set cl = ws.Cells.FindNext(After:=cl)
        Loop Until FirstFound = cl.Address
             End If
    Next ‘ etc etc
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change
`cl.EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = Cor`
to:
`ws.Range("A" & cl.Row & ":J" & cl.row).Interior.ColorIndex = Cor`

Comment: You're welcome, you can change `"A"` and `":J"` to start and end the highlight on any columns you need. Thanks for accepting my answer =)